# program stopped working (if a number isn't typed)

Tags: c#, parsing, int

```
Console.Write("\n\nHow many seats do you want to reserve?\n");
int numSeatReserveLucy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

thats the part in my code i want to be fail safe. it works fine... IF you press numbers... but if you press a letter, then the program stops working .. showing many wierd things before i close the program.
what code is it i need to get it to say like: "sorry thats not a number"
and then roll back so you can continue where you pressed wrong.

it should be fairly but i dont remember how to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f02979c7(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
int numSeatReserveLucy;

if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numSeatReserveLucy)) 
{
     Console.WriteLine("You've not entered a number!");
}
```

As @siva.k has commented out in my answer, you can also do this in a `while` loop so your program will loop until user inputs a valid formatted integer:

```
var response = Console.ReadLine(); 

// If above Console.ReadLine gets a valid integer
// the following while loop won't never executed    
while (!int.TryParse(response, out numSeatReserveLucy)) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, didn't get a number"); 
    response = Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm shocked: why the downvote? :D

Comment: Wrapped in a `while` it would role back without needing to write a whole lotta code. `var response = Console.ReadLine();
while(!int.TryParse(response, out numSeatReserveLucy)){
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, didn't get a number");  
    response = Console.ReadLine();
}`

Comment: @siva.k Absolutely, I can add your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Use `int.TryParse` instead. This method returns a boolean value to indicate parsing status. That way, if it returns false, you can prompt user to re-enter.

```
int seats = 0;
bool parseStatus = false;

parseStatus = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out seats);

if(!parseStatus)
{
 //Prompt again, may be put the whole thing in a loop till you get the right input
}
```